# Request source is in use error

Tags: excel, vba

I have linked Internet explorer from excel VBA and where i have want to do the task in loop,but whenever I am playing loop and whenever loop changing  Navigate value it is showing error of 'Request source is in use' code is below, please help

thanks in advance.

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lrow, lrow1, lrow2, lrow3 As Double
Dim lcol, lcoll As Integer
Dim a, b, c, d, e As Integer
Dim q, p, r, s, t As Integer
Dim iel As IHTMLElement
Dim iel2 As Object
Dim str As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainFile")
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details")

lrow = 0
On Error Resume Next
lrow = ws.Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, True).Row
On Error GoTo 0

If lrow > 1 Then

lcol = ws.Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, True).Column
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "abcd.com"

Do
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
ie.document.getElementById("username").Value = ws1.Range("B1").Value
ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = ws1.Range("B2").Value
ie.document.forms(0).submit

Do
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

' start loop...................

For lrow1 = 2 To lrow

    q = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Link", ws.Range("A1:" & Split(Cells(, lcol).Address, "$")(1) & "1"), 0)
    str = ws.Range(Split(Cells(, q).Address, "$")(1) & lrow1).Value

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:010"))
    ie.navigate (str) 'error place
........
```